# React navigation v1 hide an item in tab bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React navigation v1, I have a bottom tab bar set up like this

```
const HomeTabs = TabNavigator(
{
  Startside: {
    screen: MessagesList,
    navigationOptions: { tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Hjem" } },
  },
  NewMessage: {
    screen: NewMessage,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Skriv melding" },
    },
  },
  ClassList: {
    screen: ClassList,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Klasseliste" },
    },
  },
  Archive: {
    screen: Archive,
    navigationOptions: { tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Arkiv" } },
  },

  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,

    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Innstillinger" },
    },
  },
},
{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerStyle: {
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
    },
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
    style: {
      borderTopColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
    },
  },
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
  // tabBarComponent: (props) => <CustomTabsNavigator isAdmin={false} />,
  tabBarPosition: "bottom",
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false,
  focused: true,
  lazy: false,
  initialRouteName: "Startside",
}
);
```

Then I am included in the stack navigator like this

```
const MainStack = StackNavigator(
{
  ContactSelector: {
    screen: ContactSelector,
  }
},
{
  focused: true,
  lazy: true,
  initialRouteName: "Login",
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
    },
  },
  cardStyle: {
    shadowColor: "transparent",
  },
}
);
```

What I want is to show a tab bar item only certain users. Is it possible? I have been searching and searching but can't find anything and it seems like impossible. Any pointers?

```
"react-native": "^0.59.10"
```

React Navigation 1.x

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to upgrade react navigation version. I am not sure what you want is achievable but maybe you can try something like this:

```js
//TabNavigator takes an object as parameter
//so basically you need to update that object based on some condition
//you want. For instance you display the Admin tab only if user is authenticated

const Tabs = {
  Startside: {
    screen: MessagesList,
    navigationOptions: { tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Hjem" } },
  },
  NewMessage: {
    screen: NewMessage,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Skriv melding" },
    },
  },
  ClassList: {
    screen: ClassList,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Klasseliste" },
    },
  },
  Archive: {
    screen: Archive,
    navigationOptions: { tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Arkiv" } },
  },

  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,

    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarTestIDProps: { accessibilityLabel: "Innstillinger" },
    },
  },
}

//if some condition is met add the Admin tab to the navigator
if(authenticated) {
   tabs.Admin : {
       screen: Admin
   }
}
   
const HomeTabs = TabNavigator(tabs)
```

Comment: I am trying to update it as well. But for now where does this variable authenticated would be coming?

Comment: I updated the answer. I had a bug. That authenticated is just an example. Is is only a condition you want to check in order to display the tab.

Comment: Will try that, meanwhile I am trying to upgrade to v3 of react navigation. Thanks a lot. :)